# CKAN 2.2 - strange error while adding resource

Tags: python, ckan

I have the following issue:

1. I fill in the form for creating a new dataset.
2. I click the button 'Next: Add Data'. (All given data are proceeded as valid)
3. CKAN redirects me to the error page with the following text: 
   `404 Not Found. The resource could not be found. The dataset XXX could not be found.`

I checked the database and the dataset was not created.
This issue appers just sometimes. Do you have any idea what could cause such strange behaviour?

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed in your CKAN instance?

Comment: Yes, I have quite a lot (stats, text_preview, resource_proxy, recline_preview, datastore, datapusher, spatial_metadata, spatial_query, contact_us_plugin, pages, harvest, ckan_harvester) and custom extension, which add custom fields to dataset and resource.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, using suggestion from @bellisk helped me solved it. the details of my error and solution is in this ticket [Error 404 not found uploading dataset to YYC Data Collective (CKAN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58648707/error-404-not-found-uploading-dataset-to-yyc-data-collective-ckan?noredirect=1#comment103616682_58648707)

Notice that in my case plugin is "validation" but in your case it can be different however the solution is the same . Just disable the culprit plugin by removing its name in configuration file and do not forget to restart the server.

Remove plugin one by one until you find the bad one :). Hope it will help. Thanks Bellisk!