# Error 404 not found uploading dataset to YYC Data Collective (CKAN)

Tags: ckan

We have CKAN 2.7.2 and Ubuntu 14.04

I appear to be unable to upload a dataset to http://yycdatacollective.ucalgary.ca

I fill out all the metadata fields, but as soon as I hit the button to move on to the step to upload the file itself I get the following URL and error:

http://yycdatacollective.ucalgary.ca/dataset/new

[image]

But then playing with it I found a temporary workaround for it as explained in following images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

*** Not sure why when leaving the url empty then go back to fill in the url, by doing this the submission form will work. Can you please point me to where I can fix the issue. Thank you very much to all in advance! We appreciate any kind of instructions/pointers ***

Comment: This could be due to your customizations. Please test on an uncustomized and up to date version of CKAN. If there is still a bug, report it to https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues If not, apply your customizations one by one until you find the offending one. Then let us know and we can look to help.

Comment: You are probably right, thank you for your time! I will have to sip thru code since changes were made by other people.

Comment: Hello @DRead I looked into this log root@CKAN-Web:/var/log/apache2# tail -f /var/log/apache2/ckan_default.error.log while reproduced the error mentioned above, here is the log ( https://uofc-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/dule_ucalgary_ca/ETeASpONpoZDn7K-rFXRC50BlgI82Ic5OhbpuApWl6Bhbg?e=ORCAzU ), will you be able to guide me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi David, I found out, it was the validation plugin, now that I removed it out in the configuration file production.ini "ckan.plugins = stats text_view image_view validation" this error is no longer there. Thanks @DRead for your support! much appreciate!